# Как сделать появление ImageView при определенном условии android?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-view

У себя в приложении я работаю с списками сообщений (входящие, исходящие, черновики). Эти списки я тяну с сервера, и в ответе всегда получаю количество, которое называется в ответе `count`. Иногда бывает так, что это количество равно 0, а иногда оно >0. Вот у меня появилось желание выводить какую-то картинку (ждуна например) если сообщений нету. Вот я смог сделать так, чтобы у меня выводилось количество сообщений, ну то есть эта переменная. Вроде все ок, но вот как сделать так, чтобы если все-таки сообщений нету, то мой список скрывался, и выводилось на экран изображение. Вот как я пробую сейчас:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
Integer count = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getCount();

if (count > 0) {
messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, (), type);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} if (count == 0) {
recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

На данный момент выводятся сообщения, но дальше почему-то дело не двигается. Пробовал обычное `TextView` выводить, но тоже глухо. Походу я что-то делаю не так. Но что именно не могу понять.

Comment: Сообщения в RV выводятся в блоке if (count > 0) ? 
А в блоке if (count == 0) прячется RV и тосты выводятся, верно?

Comment: да все верно, пробовал для проверки скрывать RV если есть сообщения, то все работает вроде

Comment: так а пробовали поверх RV наложить картинку и менять ей видимость противоположно RV?

Comment: вот этого я не смог добиться, я уже понял что картинка лежит под списком, и поэтому обычное скрытие списка не работает. Это нужно как-то поднять картинку над списком, чтобы список был под картинкой?

Comment: Это не важно, если вы меняете видимость RV на GONE. А попробуйте со старта задать видимость для RV и IV наоборот (т.е. IV видимо а RV не видимо) 
Будет ли картинка правильно отображаться?

Comment: типа в onCreate? или при вызове функции для отправки запроса?

Comment: да где угодно, хоть в XML. Может просто не правильно сверстали, всякое бывает

Comment: ну что я могу сказать, я вот только что попробовал переместить imageview над списком, и теперь висит только картинка а список теперь не видно

Comment: Меняли видимость или расположение виджетов в  XML?

Comment: расположение, видимость пока не трогал, просто картинку поместил над списком, в коде

Comment: Теперь попробуйте изменять видимость VISIBLE -> GONE

Comment: да картинка скрылась

Comment: и RV появился? 
не забудьте RV делать еще видимым. В представленном коде этого нету (только скрытие)

Comment: rv появился, но получение кол-ва у меня происходит в другой функции, где я не могу найти по id картинку, либо у меня срабатывает исключение

Comment: А как вы можете найти RV а IV нет? Они же в одном лейауте

Comment: короче у меня вроде как получилось)) могу опубликовать ответ, может где еще подкорректируете

Comment: Ну и отлично что получилось :)

Comment: все-равно как-то сомнительно если честно) сейчас наверное добавлю ответ, может я все-таки что-то пропустил, потому-что вроде работает, но как-то стремновато

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/received"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivNoMess"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:visibility="gone" //Установить сразу видимость GONE

        android:src="@drawable/ic_logout" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" //Установить сразу видимость GONE
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_res"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

А в коде уже менять на `visible` там где надо

Comment: вот сейчас пробую, вроде все ок, но теперь почему-то не могу по-нормальному показать картинку

Comment: что подразумеваете под "по-нормальному показать картинку" ?

Comment: это значит, что когда у меня нету сообщений то скрыть список, и показать картинку

Comment: А каким образом вы инициализируете RV?

Comment: я опять протупил)))) забыл объявить iv и как результат мне нечего было скрывать)

Comment: ну вот........)))

Comment: та не то слово, стыдоба)))